# How to reduce RAM memory while loading android app

Tags: android, memory, ram

I have created an app, which is taking more RAM usage while loading it self around 28MB+.

This app contains around 6+ .so files (required to support different android versions.) but these .so files are loading later I mean not immediately.

Lot more String variables too. This application requires platform signatures for some requirements. But for initial setup, those APIs will not get called (I mean platform related API)

I have just tried like just loading Initial activity it self, this itself taking 28MB.

What will happen when an app is loaded/launched?

I want to know like, while loading the app itself, all the resources, .so files, other activities, services irrespective of top activity will be loaded and placed in memory?

Is that causing more RAM usage?

I need more information about how android will allocate RAM while loading application...

which is causing more RAM usage?

your help will be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: have you check this article? https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html and eclipse MAT plugin will help you

Comment: Dhawal, I know that but still during initial loading activity it self, it is taking huge RAM. During this time, I am no where used memory allocations. And  also I dint find any logs like GC_CONCURRENT, GC* etc. Found " OpenGLRenderer(27503): Render dirty regions requested: true " but dint understood why this has come...

Comment: Dhaval, I read https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html and executed "adb shell dumpsys meminfo packageName -d" 
found that on 5.0 devices, Graphics memory also showing which is unavoidable.

Comment: Also check eclipse MAT which is show you all activity objects whichever consuming memory

Comment: Dhaval, adding to that, I just want to know on which basis RAM is allocated to an app?
I just wrote test app and ran in device.. it took 5MB RAM.. it dint have any operations.. just activity only. 
I have another app, which may requires byte array for processing images/screen captures... so requires Graphics operations(I hope) but not immediately after starting the main activity. but RAM is allocated for Graphics when the app is started it self.. 
I just want to restrict that... is it possible?
Because of Graphics, My app's RAM is showing 25MB more which is more..

Answer (score 0):

Now in addition of using Eclipse MAT to detect memory leaks, here is a library for your app to detect leaks easily.
https://github.com/square/leakcanary

most of memory leaks in android are Context or Activity leaks.